# How to establish adb USB protocol between two linux devices

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, adb

Basically, the aim is to establish an adb protocol via usb between two linux computers by using adb source codes.

Envinronment is Ubuntu 14.0.4. There's **android-tools-adbd** (adb daemon) package ready for use in the pool with its source available.

We are able to build the package from source or use already-built one successfully by using adb connect (TCP/IP dependent). There's no problem on adb connection via TCP/IP if two computers are connected to the same network.

Unfortunately, we are not able to set a USB connection between two computers with an A to A (both male) cable. Not sure if there's a driver for it either.

**Question is:**

***How to set a USB protocol between two linux computers so that adb communication can be done via USB?***

Is there any solution for it?